# Magento products and categories url prefix

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting, prefix

I want to make custom rewrite to categories and products url.
In example I have categories :

```
Category 1 > Subcat 11 > Subsubcat 11,
```

I want to have url like

```
www.store.com/categories/category-1/
www.store.com/categories/subcat-11/ 
www.store.com/categories/subsubcat-11/
```

instead of

```
www.store.com/category-1/subcat-11/ or www.store.com/category-1/subcat-11/subsubcat-11/
```

And also I want `www.store.com/products/products-name.html` instead of `www.store.com/category-1/products-name.html` or `www.store.com/category-1/subcat-11/products-name.html`

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add custom URL rewrite in admin panel: Catalog >> URL Rewrite Management >> Add new rule.

Maybe try to use some module for this:
for example I found this one, but haven't tried id.
http://extensions.activo.com/seo-friendly-categories-for-magento.html

or to try this maybe:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32328/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes i knew the URL Rewrite Management. I have thousands of products so it will be time consuming if i change the rules one by one.

Comment: Thanks very much, i tried the extension and make some modifications and now it works.

Comment: This is only a partial answer. Still needs to answer about the product urls prefix.

Answer (score 0):

yes for your solution one good extension is available  to make category url seo friendly with nested category and it is free to install to manage custom url for category

use below link and check it out i am sure it will sure help you [seo friendly categories](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/seo-friendly-categories-7026.html)